# Genus of a curve equals to -1 in SageMath

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sagemath

> What does it mean when Sage computes genus of a projective plane curve to be -1?

Input:

```
x,y,z = QQ['x,y,z'].gens()
C = Curve(x^4 + 10*x^2*y*z + 5*y^2*z^2)
C.genus()
```

Output:

```
-1
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. The curve has genus $0$. You could make a [trac ticket](https://trac.sagemath.org/) or raise the issue on [ASKSAGE](https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/).

Comment: I am not sure it is a bug. I got even genus -2 for some curves. Either it is a bug or it was intention - but then I am not sure what would be the meaning of negative genus.

Comment: Negative arithmetic genus can happen, but Sage's documentation says it calculates geometric genus which is never negative for irreducible curves (it's defined to be the genus of the normalization, which is a smooth curve). One of the other reasons you should think that this curve having geometric genus $-1$ is a bug is that $g_a-g_g$ is determined by the singularities for a curve, and we have exactly two singular points at $[0:1:0]$ and $[0:0:1]$ which are isomorphic. So whatever this quantity is should be even. But $6-(-1)$ isn't.

Comment: The [documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/curves/sage/schemes/curves/projective_curve.html) for Sage even says the (geometric) genus is a non-negative integer. I computed the genus with Magma for this curve, and it is $0$. I think this is a bug.

Comment: I posted the same question on https://ask.sagemath.org/question/48979/geometric-genus-of-a-curve-equals-to-1-in-sagemath/.

Comment: Based on the answer there, it sounds like user error or bad documentation for what input is allowable.